# mvc view not renders when i change its location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to render mvc view file from a remote location like suppose `test.cshtml` file will be stored in s3 bucket and it is public accessable. I already tried like bellow but it says error-

> The view 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/testtt123/test.cshtml' or its
>   master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //return View("~/Views/Home/test.cshtml"); // this works fine
    return View("https://s3.amazonaws.com/testtt123/test.cshtml"); // this not works
}
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsGmX.png)

[image]

Whtats the easy way to do it? I dont want to use any 3rd party library. How can i do it with mvc5? Thanks in advance

Comment: fetch the content using a HttpClient and then display it using @Html.Raw(vaue);

Answer (score 3):

This scenario is not supported by ASP.NET MVC. The view file must be stored on the local file system. A network location may work too, but will slow you down. But there is no way the framework will pull a view over an HTTP connection.